# Is an interrupt a signal, according to the C spec?

Tags: c, embedded, language-lawyer, interrupt, c11

C11 5.1.2.3/5:

> When the processing of the abstract machine is interrupted by receipt
>   of a signal, the values of objects that are neither lock-free atomic
>   objects nor of type volatile sig_atomic_t are unspecified, as is the
>   state of the floating-point environment. The value of any object
>   modified by the handler that is neither a lock-free atomic object nor
>   of type volatile sig_atomic_t becomes indeterminate when the handler
>   exits, as does the state of the floating-point environment if it is
>   modified by the handler and not restored to its original state.

This question is specifically about embedded systems, in a situation where there is no operating system-like setup.

On an embedded system classic signals (POSIX style) do not exist. Say we have an interrupt which calls multiple functions, all of whom work on the same ((semi-) global) variable, but this variable is not used from an out-of-interrupt context. Something like

```
static enum State state;

static void setStateTo1(void)
{
    state = stateOne;
}

static void setStateTo2(void)
{
    state = stateTwo;
}

void ISR(void)
{
    if (state == stateOne)
        setStateTo2();
    else
        setStateTo1();
}
```

Two questions:

1. Is an interrupt a signal?
2. Is the above code an example of undefined behaviour, because `state` is not `volatile`?

Comment: How do you install those "interrup handlers"? If you use `signal` for this, then these are signal handlers in the sense of the standard and then yes you should only use `volatile sigatomic_t` to communicate. If this is a system specific set of functions, you'd have too look up that documentation, the C standard can't tell you any about this.

Comment: As stated in the question, this is about embedded systems (I will add the tag to make it more clear), this this is literally the processor deciding that we are now going to run this function because some event happened

Comment: We can only assume that the C language is meant to run on a special device which doesn't have OP code instructions, assembler language or interrupts. Otherwise the language would have standard support for computers. Even C++ supports inline assembler, but not C.

Comment: From a pure practical point of view: Since the code shown accesses the variable from just one single thread (and the ISR and the function it calls is a kind of thread), I don't see any need to make it `volatile` or atomic. Having said this, you need to make sure that while the ISR or any called function runs, it can **not** be called again. This is standard on most embedded systems, but you can make it happen. And you need to make sure that no other thread (like `main()` and its called functions) accesses this variable.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The term "signal" refers to a specific thing whose behaviour is defined by the standard (C11 7.14 "Signal handling") ; that definition includes that the signal  has a number, and can interrupt execution by jumping to a handler installed by the `signal` function, and so on.

The standard does not cover any other sort of asynchronous code execution besides signals and threads.

If your implementation offers any other sort of interrupt that doesn't follow the specification of signals, and the interrupt handler changes the behaviour of the abstract machine, then we could either say that the implementation is non-conforming, or that the code to install the signal handler causes undefined behaviour.

To be well-defined you can have the handlers do nothing besides writing volatile atomic variables.

So, your second question is beyond the scope of the Standard. In Standard C the optimizer could remove all of those functions as unused if they are never called by the program.

In reality an implementation that offers non-standard interrupts will be defining its own behaviour under its own purview, and you could consider it an extended dialect of C with that added functionality.

Comment: So what is a signal, according to the standard?

Comment: it does mention `5.2.3      Signals and interrupts`

Comment: @P__J__ if you refer to 5.2.3 "signals and interrupts", it refers to execution being interrupted by a signal.  Any other kind of interruption other than signals is not covered by the standard.

Comment: `Functions shall be implemented such that theymay be interrupted at anytime by a signal` any source of interruption is a signal.

Comment: @Cheiron There's not really a formal definition. A "signal" in the C language, is something that utilizes the abstract library signal.h. A "conforming freestanding implementation" (read: embedded systems compiler) need not provide support for signal.h, it is optional.

Comment: @P__J__ No, it only says that functions shall be implemented so that they may be interrupted by a signal, but it doesn't define what a signal is. `signal.h` is most definitely not used for interrupt handling in any embedded system I know of.

Comment: I re-worded the first part of my answer

Comment: @M.M Is it true though that the (C11) standard only covers asynchronous execution through threads? Isn't the abstract concepts of "sequenced before/after" etc also meant to cover other forms of parallel processing such as multiple cores instruction caching or pipelining? Or indeed interrupts?

Comment: @Lundin I see what you mean but not really sure what a better choice of words would be (the question is mainly about interrupt handlers executing C code so I don't want to go off on too much of a side track to maintain pedantic accuracy)

Comment: @M.M Well, if you want to go on this sidetrack, I would be very interested.

Answer (score 0):

The authors of the Standard regarded many things as *outside their jurisdiction*.  If an implementation were to use the stack in a way that would malfunction unpredictably if any interrupt occurred during program execution, and consequently required that the code it generates must only be run in situations where no interrupts could occur, such a limitation would not make the implementation non-conforming, though it would render it unsuitable for many purposes.

A quality implementation which is designed to be suitable for low-level programming on a particular platform should be expected to either extend the skeletal abstraction model given in the C Standard to include any parts of the platform's abstraction model that would be useful for that purpose, or else document a sound reason for doing otherwise, but Quality of Implementation issues are outside the Standard's jurisdiction.  Whether a particular implementation should be expected to work usefully in cases beyond those contemplated by the Standard depends upon whether its designers were interested in making it suitable for a wide range of low-level programming tasks, or interested only suitability for purposes contemplated by the Standard.