# How to write strictly conforming interrupt service routines (on AVR)

Tags: c, language-lawyer, interrupt-handling, avr-gcc, sig-atomic-t

The C Standard mandates that a signal handler may access only objects of type `sig_atomic_t` (besides lock-free atomics). Accesses to objects of other types produce UB. An interrupt service routine resembles a signal handler, so this restriction must be obeyed when writing ISRs.

avr-libc's `signal.h` is broken in that it does not declare type `sig_atomic_t`, though it does declare a variable of that name, of type `volatile signed char`.  Presumably, that was meant to be a `typedef`.

But if you want an ISR to access, say, a `systick` counter of type `uint32_t` then that would produce UB.

Are there any special precautions / exceptions from the standard that avr-gcc imposes, so that it would be possible to write a strictly conforming ISR?

Comment: Not sure that «special precautions / exceptions from the standard» and «strictly conforming» are not mutually-exclusive things

Comment: The C standard defines a bare minimum set of facilities for signal handling, with extreme limitations on what you can do in a signal handler.  If you're writing real code, you don't work with the C standard definition of what's acceptable (because it really isn't acceptable); you work with the limitations imposed by the O/S on which you're working.  POSIX requires systems to provide a lot more flexibility for signal handlers.  Trying to write a "strictly (standard C) conforming ISR" is, IMO, a nonsensical idea — don't try it.  If you have a coding standard that says "thou shalt", it's broken.

Comment: Which version of the C language are you asking about?  And are you asserting that avr-libc is broken *because* it declares `sig_atomic_t` as `signed char`?  Or if you are saying that avr-libc `signal.h` is *generally* broken, then how can this be a language-lawyer question?  You need to write code that works on your target implementation, and it doesn't matter what the language spec says if your implementation works differently.

Comment: See https://www.nongnu.org/avr-libc/user-manual/group__util__atomic.html for an example with a non-atomic data type.

Comment: Note, however, that `signed char` is an integer type, and thus a viable candidate for `sig_atomic_t`.  If avr-libc defines `sig_atomic_t` as `signed char` then that does not conflict with any published version of the C language spec.

Comment: @JohnBollinger `signal.h` defines a variable of name `sig_atomic_t` with type `signed char` ... but it should be a `typedef`.

Comment: @JonathanLeffler I'm not talking about POSIX, I'm talking about `avr-gcc` and target `avr` on bare-metal.

Comment: "An interrupt service routine resembles a signal handler" does not mean that it is a signal handler. It could also be viewed as resembling a thread, though it isn't exactly the same thing. However, I think that that is a more useful comparison (but only a comparison).

Comment: I think the question "how  to write a strictly conforming ISR" is too broad. If you would limit your question to "how to implement a `uint32_t systick` counter based on a timer ISR when atomic operations are possible only for 8-bit types", it would be easy to propose solutions.

Comment: A C implementation running on bare metal is called "freestanding". A conforming freestanding implementation does not need to provide `signal.h` or accept programs that rely on it.  I don't know about avr-gcc and avr-libc in particular, but a typical freestanding implementation provides few or none of the standard library functions, so a strictly conforming program running on such an implementation cannot do much of anything useful.  It needs to pierce through C's abstract machine to details of the physical host machine in order to do much.

Comment: And for using a "systick counter of type uint32_t" that is read by non-ISR code and updated by a single ISR, the burden for coding for proper synchronization control will be on all accesses from non-ISR code.

Comment: This [question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/60864187/1778275) may be useful.

Answer (score 2):

> How to write strictly conforming interrupt service routines (on AVR)

As you tagged the question `avr-gcc`, I'll assume GCC<sup>1</sup> in the remainder. It's not possible to do it in a performing way due to 2 reasons:

1. There is no way to write an ISR in a conforming way. avr-gcc uses attributes to implement this.
2. avr-gcc implements neither atomic types nor atomic builtins (where the latter are compiler specific of course, so you can ignore them for conforming discussion).  Even if avr-gcc implemented atomic types, using libatomic would be considered inappropriate due to its resource consumption by most AVR folks. And even the simple atomic accesses that could be performed by the compiler without resorting to lib code are not implemented. Take for example:

   ```cpp
   int var;
   _Atomic int aaa;

   int get_var_atomic (void)
   {
       int v;
       __atomic_load (&var, &v, __ATOMIC_SEQ_CST);
       return v;
   }

   int get_var_atomic_n (void)
   {
        return __atomic_load_n (&var, __ATOMIC_SEQ_CST);
   }

   int get_aaa (void)
   {
       return aaa;
   }
   ```

   All three functions will forward to `__atomic_load_2`, which does not exists (as of avr-gcc v13), and respective insns don't exist, either. Or more precisely: there are generic versions in libatomic, but bachend avr has libatomic disabled.

   So the closest you can do is to use these primitives to implement atomic magic, and also to provide these functions.  By its very nature, these functions cannot be inlined. So the only reasonable approach is to implement this in the compiler backend itself, which is somewhere in `./gcc/config/avr/avr.md`<sup>2,3</sup>.

---

<sup>1</sup> Hence `avr-gcc` or `avr-g++` and AVR-LibC.  Dunno how the situation is for other compiler brands like IAR.

<sup>2</sup> You can use the vanilla non-atomic loads and stores code emitters, but you'll have to get an 8-bit tmp reg `Rx` so you can

```
in Rx, SREG
cli
<vanilla-code>
out SREG, Rx
```

for the simple cases. `__tmp_reg__` can't be used here for obvious reasons.

<sup>3</sup> I just got ranted for globally switching off IRQs.  So if you want to avoid that, you'll have to go the libatomic way and allocate semaphores. No need so say that this is extremely expensive compared to the usual approaches.